# sending saved audio file via email in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, email, attachment, audio-recording

I wrote a program that is able to save audio on iphone by using AVAudioFramework.
Now what i need to do is send this saved audio to any contact on the phone via email as an attachment.
Could some help me please? I'm running out of time.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [MFMailComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html), specifically the `addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:` method.

Answer (score 0):

Send it as an attachment (using MFMailComposeViewController).  Finding the contact info is up to you.